# Contact Name from Phone No

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I am getting below error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 16:46:59.093: E/AndroidRuntime(4064):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:90)
```

Using below code.

```
public String getContactNameFromNumber(String number) {
        // define the columns I want the query to return
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME,
                Contacts.Phones.NUMBER };


        // encode the phone number and build the filter URI
        Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode(number));

        // query time
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        // if the query returns 1 or more results
        // return the first result
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String name = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME));
            return name;
        }
```

Any one has Idea why I am getting this error.

Thank You.

Comment: try using context.getContentResolver.query(...);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
String address="3791783465"; //phone number you already have

Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(address));           
Cursor cs= context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);

if(cs.getCount()>0)
{
     cs.moveToFirst();    
     Toast.makeText(context,cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     cs.close();
}
else
     Toast.makeText(context,"Unknown",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```